# Trying to modify project template, but folder seems to be missing files

Tags: xcode, templates

I'm trying to add a custom code template into Xcode. Based on my reading, this is the procedure I've come up with.

First, access the folder path

> Application/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/Application

Second, make a copy of one of the existing folders to use as a starting point.

Third, change that folder name to what I want.

The part that I'm having trouble with is that there are no files with the code that I want to modify, such as **PROJECTNAME**.xcodeproj, anyfilename.h, anyfilename.h, etc., there is only MainStoryBoard_iPad(and iPhone).storyboard, ViewcontrolleriPad(and iPhone).Xib, TemplateIcon.tiff and TemplateInfo.plist.

What's the proper way to do this? What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you trying to create? A project Template or a File Template?

- If you want to create a new File Template, you need to copy a whole `"*.xctemplate"` folder from `"/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates"` (that you will use as an example/starting point) to `"~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/File Templates"`.
- If you want to create a new Project Template, do the same with one `"*.xctemplate"` folder from `"/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates"` to `"~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates"`
- If the `"File Templates"`/`"Project Templates"` folder is not present in App Support, create them.

**Don't copy the template into the Xcode bundle itself** as it is not intended to (and violates the sandbox concept, and will be overridden the next time you upgrade your Xcode version) but **use the `Application Support` folder for that** as it is its very purpose.

Once you have copied one `.xctemplate` folder from the Xcode bundle to the corresponding App Support folder, you can modify the content of the `.xctemplate` to fit your needs.

---

Now **for the fact that you don't have any xcodeproj in the xctemplate folder**, this is because the project that is created by a Project Template **is not defined using a xcodeproj file**, but rather with **keys in the TemplateInfo.plist** file.

For example, in `"Project Templates/Mac/Mac Base.xctemplate/TemplateInfo.plist"` you can see a key named `"Project"` with subkeys `"Configurations"`, `"SDK"`, and `"SharedSettings"` that defines some Build Settings for the xcodeproj to be created by the template.

Moreover, be aware that **templates have some kind of "inheritance" concept**, each template being able to have "ancestors" that define common keys:

- Open the `"TemplateInfo.plist"` file and look at the `"ancestors"` key
- You will find here an array of identifiers for the ancestors of the selected template. For example, the `"Cocoa Application.xctemplate"` template have `"com.apple.dt.unit.cocoaApplicationBase"` as one of its ancestor.
- Then go and find the template whose identifier is the one found in the ancestor key (in my example, it is the `"Cocoa Application Base.xctemplate"` template, as in its `TemplateInfo.plist` you can see that its `"Identifier"` key is the `"com.apple.dt.unit.cocoaApplicationBase"` we saw above).

And You can go up like that until the base template, having some kind of "inheritence" for the template definition.

Comment: I'd like to use custom template which has modified code for my favorite and often using. 
How to add private often used code into custom template?

Comment: Do what I described in my answer: duplicate the existing template you want to base onto, and alter its `<ancestor>` key to make it be based on the main template. Then add your custom code. Note that you could also create a **code snippet** instead of trying to create a custom template, that would be much more easier to create (simple Drag & Drop of the code in Xcode to the Code Snippets library) and can be applied anywhere in your projects (even the existing ones).